# How to create valid factories with FactoryBot when different columns need to correspond with one another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, factory-bot

I have a model called Event. It looks like this:

```rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :events

  validates :event_category, presence: true

  enum event_category: {
    add_to_library: 0,
    change_completion_status: 1,
    favorite_game: 2,
    new_user: 3,
    following: 4
  }
end
```

I was running into errors where users were able to create Events where `eventable` didn't match the corresponding type (e.g. `GamePurchase` represents a game in a user's library and is what `eventable` is supposed to be when the category is `add_to_library`), so I added [a Postgres check constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) that checks to make sure the event_category and eventable_type match. The problem is that my event factories really don't like this constraint and tries to create records where the `event_category` and `eventable_type` don't match. Is there a way to fix this?

My factories for Event look like this:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :game_purchase_library_event, class: 'Event', aliases: [:event] do
    user
    association(:eventable, factory: :game_purchase)
    event_category { :add_to_library }
  end

  factory :game_purchase_completion_event, class: 'Event' do
    user
    association(:eventable, factory: :game_purchase)
    event_category { :change_completion_status }
    differences do
      # Pick two random values
      { completion_status: GamePurchase.completion_statuses.values.sample(2) }
    end
  end

  factory :favorite_game_event, class: 'Event' do
    user
    association(:eventable, factory: :favorite_game)
    event_category { :favorite_game }
  end

  factory :new_user_event, class: 'Event' do
    user
    association(:eventable, factory: :user)
    event_category { :new_user }
  end

  factory :following_event, class: 'Event' do
    user
    association(:eventable, factory: :relationship)
    event_category { :following }
  end
end
```

I'm getting factory_bot lint failures like this:

```
FactoryBot::InvalidFactoryError: The following factories are invalid:

* game_purchase_library_event+favorite_game - PG::CheckViolation: ERROR:  new row for relation "events" violates check constraint "event_category_type_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (f9fb682b-8ae6-4d79-b91a-d17c58b4d02c, 29157, 4, 2021-02-28 01:05:27.591942, 2021-02-28 01:05:27.591942, 2, null, GamePurchase).
 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
* game_purchase_library_event+new_user - PG::CheckViolation: ERROR:  new row for relation "events" violates check constraint "event_category_type_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (a8de4c5c-cdc2-4bdb-9a8f-a09cf1813dac, 13791, 5, 2021-02-28 01:05:27.650202, 2021-02-28 01:05:27.650202, 3, null, GamePurchase).
 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
* game_purchase_library_event+following - PG::CheckViolation: ERROR:  new row for relation "events" violates check constraint "event_category_type_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (96d11b13-3cdd-44e2-80e5-e4a070ef8ac8, 25781, 6, 2021-02-28 01:05:27.705169, 2021-02-28 01:05:27.705169, 4, null, GamePurchase).
 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was being caused by the automatic generation of enum traits, which is why there were those incompatible traits that were causing the linter to fail. The feature [is described here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/18bbc5b5822e32aa8259a1f67fb6296fcf04a2b0/GETTING_STARTED.md#enum-traits), you can disable it with `FactoryBot.automatically_define_enum_traits = false` (I created a `factory_bot.rb` file in my initializers directory and disabled it there).